# Not getting the login page on Jenkins after enabling security

Tags: jenkins, devops

I took a copy of Jenkins_Home to build a copy of the running instance of jenkins on port 8083. I enabled security by following these steps:

1. Select jenkins own database for user authentication.
2. Manage Jenkins -> Create a new user —> admin credentials

Now if I check the config of jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins I can see that **useSecurity** tag has value true ( earlier it was false )

3. Restart jenkins

My jenkins server times -out at the login page. I checked that and someone mentioned that login works on default port 8080, so I changed the port in /etc/default/jenkins to 8080. Still when I give :port in my browser the URL times-out on port 8080 and I get an error :

This page isn’t working

If the problem continues, contact the site owner.

HTTP ERROR 401

How do I resolve this issue ?